# Uber API - HTTPS needed for Price Estimates?

Tags: wordpress, uber-api

I use Uber's API to create a WordPress plugin so people can order taxis to your physical location.

I'm looking at integrating the Price Estimates using the endpoint here - https://developer.uber.com/v1/endpoints/#price-estimates - I've a solution but having a bit of problem implementing it.

I'm getting an error on testing which in Google Chrome Developer Tools which states "Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers."

I suspect it's due to the fact that the testing server is insecure, as the app  Origin ID and Redirect ID begins with https:// (as I'm unable to add http://).

Will I be able to access the price estimates over http at all? I'm using the server_token way of authentication as feel it's probably the best way to do it.

Any help would be gratefully received :)

Comment: You should be able to receive this information from the Uber API, after you authenticate your end for Uber to post the information you are requesting. Refer to this page: https://developer.uber.com/v1/auth/

Comment: Uber don't allow you to put your app Origin/Redirect URL's as http, and I'm testing this on a non SSL server. Would this cause an issue? My code looks okay...

Comment: Yes, this is an issue. Uber explicitly states, at the top of the page I refereed you to, that any communication with Uber servers must be over SSL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Uber API only, and will only ever, support HTTPS.