# Getting a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." Error

Tags: uber-api

Further to the previous question - [Uber API - HTTPS needed for Price Estimates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28420127/uber-api-https-needed-for-price-estimates) - I have set up https on our site.

My App on Uber Developer is set up with the redirect URL & Origin URL being the https domain.

Following the code on this page - https://developer.uber.com/v1/api-reference/#request-response - I've tried testing the code given here:-

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Token YOUR_SERVER_TOKEN");
xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.uber.com/v1/products?latitude=37.7759792&longitude=-122.41823');
```

Unfortuantely I'm getting the error "Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': The object's state must be OPENED.".

I've then switched around the .setRequestHeader & .open lines and I am getting the following error:-

"XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.uber.com/v1/estimates/price?start_latitude=53.4521477&start_longitude=-2.2750512&end_latitude=53.4522973&end_longitude=-2.275001. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://milliondollarwiki.co.uk' is therefore not allowed access."

Here is the final code in question:-

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.uber.com/v1/estimates/price?start_latitude=' + position.coords.latitude + '&start_longitude=' + position.coords.longitude + '&end_latitude=53.4522973&end_longitude=-2.275001');
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Token bTVn8k_wF3JpmHlZ0GhdbMWaLgbLMSaYof8rs-S_");        
xhr.send();
```

The URL which is interacting in the Uber API is in a subfolder of the Redirect & Origin URLs, but I don't think that should cause an issue.

Any idea on what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right I managed to get it fixed :). I had to recreate the app which took a minute or two but it was fine. Odd :-/

Comment: Same thing here – recreating the app seemed to fix it for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I looked up your application and at this time you have

`https://milliondollarwiki.co.uk/scratchpad/`

as the ORIGIN URI.  For CORS, you should only be specifying the server address without a specified path (and no trailing slash).  Try changing it to:

`https://milliondollarwiki.co.uk`

and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: Hi @scott-biggart,

Thanks for this :)

I have changed to both `https://milliondollarwiki.co.uk`, `https://milliondollarwiki.co.uk/` and the sub page that the code is running on, and I am still getting the same error :(